# How much is the capacitance between the Casimir plates that are shown to be attracted due to vacuum fluctuations

Tags: quantum-electrodynamics

Casimir found a quantum force making two uncharged conducting plates (capacitor) to be attracted. This is due to quantum fluctuations where charged pair bubbles. As a result, the plates may have been charged. What will be the Casimir capacitance, accordingly.

Comment: Capacitance has nothing to do with charge on the plates but everything to do with the plate geometry and separation, so it is given by the usual parallel plate capacitor equation $\frac{\epsilon_0 A}{d}$ where A is the area and d is the separation

Comment: In physics there are several types of capacitance, the one you define is called the geometrical capacitance. However, a quantum capacitance is also used to describe microscopic devices. You may like to see this   http://www.ece.sunysb.edu/~serge/63.pdf

Comment: For  the essence of quantum capacitance please visit: 
 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_capacitance#cite_note-Luryi-1

Comment: This effect is solely due to the 2D electron gas not shielding external electric fields and functions as a pseudo-capacitance